# How to calculate base displacement addresses

Tags: assembly, memory-address

I'm learning very basic assembly language stuff starting with some pseudo-code.

If the instruction "10(50)" translates to: Go to memory location [50 + 10] -- i.e., this is base displacement addresses,

and if the instruction "@50" translates to: Go to memory location[[50]], i.e., find what [50] is pointing to (call that x), and find [x]

What does "10(@50") mean? It seems to me like the instruction is ambiguous. Do you resolve the @50 part and *then* add the displacement? Or do you add the displacement to the @50 and then resolve @60?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Which assembler is this ? For Which chip are you trying to learn this ? You would help your readers a lot if you could format your post so as to separate your source from your text.

Comment: It's not for an assembler or even a chip, it's before that level. Basically my question is: when using base displacement addressing, do you first resolve the base address and then add the displacement, or do you add the displacement to the base and then resolve the result?

Comment: Somebody can coorect me, but best I know, the answer to that is dependent on the chip itself. A concrete example with the actual registers and offset in question would help me (and several others, I'm confident) understand the question better.

Comment: Since you're writing pseudo-code, it can mean whatever you want it to mean. :) That said, the expression `10(@50)` would, to my intuition, completely resolve `@50` first, then apply `10`. So it would reference address `[10+[50]]`. If you specify what the processor AND the assembler is, even as an example, then a specific, correct answer can be given for that configuration.

Comment: Hmmm, the way the question was given to us (this is for an intro systems course), no assembler or chip was mentioned. If I have to pick one though, how about IA32 on an intel chip? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves me right, it would have to be `[[50 + 10]]` on IA-32. As in:

```
JMP DWORD PTR 10[50]  ; Jump to the 32-bit address located at address 60
```

The one example of post-indexed memory-indirect addressing that comes to mind is the 6502, where you'd write it as `(imm8),Y`. For example:

```
LDY #10
LDA (50),Y  ; Loads the 16-bit word at 50, adds the value of Y to it, and
            ; uses the result as the effective address for an 8-bit load
            ; into register A
```

Note that the index has to be in register `Y`; so you can't write something like `LDA (50),10`.
In fact, I can't recall ever having come across a processor that includes such an addressing mode. Which is not to say that one doesn't exist.